# Why can't I get a right output?

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to get "AbeSimp" but it returned "AbeSimpson" and ignored the first condition. Please tell me the reason and how I can fix this problem.

-----  code -----

```
def username_generator(first_name, last_name):
  if len(first_name) > 3 and len(last_name) > 4:
    username = first_name[:3] + last_name[:4]
    return username
  else:
    username = first_name + last_name
    return username

print(username_generator("Abe", "Simpson"))
```

Comment: you are using `and` in if statement. Both conditions have to be true for it to work

Comment: I see! Thank you so much! I will be careful for it:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to break the if statement and check each one separately

```
def username_generator(first_name, last_name):
    if len(first_name) > 3:
        username = first_name[:3]
    else:
        username = first_name

    if len(last_name) > 4:
        username += last_name[:4]
    else:
        username += last_name
return username

print(username_generator("Abe", "Simpson"))
```

The above code is a restructuring of your code. However, in python things are a bit more simpler.

lets say :

```
first_name = 'Ab'
last_name = 'Sim'

username = first_name[:3] + last_name[:4]
```

This will output:

```
AbSim
```

So you don't need to do a lot of the above code. Python does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(first_name) > 3 and len(last_name) > 4:
```

the length of abe is 3 characters and when comparing 3 > 3 , your condition is not met and gets to the else part.